# Python - Waiting untill a number of operations are done in concurrent.futures

Tags: python, python-3.x, process, multiprocessing

This is why I try to do using python and concurrent.futures library.

Assume that you have a dictionary input as :

```
input = {'1': {'Joe','Sal', 'Murry','Q}}, {'2':{'Dana','White'}},{'3':{'ice','cream','water','cola','Butter'}}
```

The function that will be run in the executors will only take one parameter. something like :

```
def printMyInput(mystring):
    print(mystring)
```

so the specification is that you can run the set in `input['1']` parallel.

```
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
   results = [executor.sumbit(printMyInput, x) for x in input['1'])
```

This is done only for `input['1']`. for running `input['2']` the processes for `input['1']` has to be done first. and for `input['3']` the processes for `input['2']` needs to be done and so on. I can not come up with a way of doing that. and I really need some help.

Answer (score 0):

The executor will block until all processes are complete. You can loop the executor call to run each stage in sequence.

Try this code:

```
import concurrent.futures

from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support

input = {'1': ['Joe','Sal', 'Murry','Q'], 
         '2':['Dana','White'],
         '3':['ice','cream','water','cola','Butter']}

def printMyInput(mystring):
    print(mystring)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()  # needed for Windows
    for k in input:
       with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
          print('>> Process ', k)
          results = [executor.submit(printMyInput, x) for x in input[k]]
```

Output

```
>> Process  1
Joe
Sal
Murry
Q
>> Process  2
Dana
White
>> Process  3
ice
cream
water
cola
Butter
```

------  Update  ------

To test the looping structure, I added a random sleep to the callback to vary the process time. For the code to work correctly, the `for` must be above the `with`. A new `ProcessPoolExecutor` needs to be created for each stage.

Here is the test code:

```
import concurrent.futures
import random, time

from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support

input = {'1':['Joe','Sal', 'Murry','Q'], 
         '2':['Dana','White'],
         '3':['ice','cream','water','cola','Butter']}

def printMyInput(mystring):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,4))  # random sleep time
    print(mystring)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()  # needed for Windows
    for k in input:
       with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
          print('>> Process ', k)
          results = [executor.submit(printMyInput, x) for x in input[k]]
```

------  Update #2 ------

I did more testing. You can switch the loop structure as long as you block while gathering results.

```
import concurrent.futures
import random, time

from multiprocessing import Process, freeze_support

input = {'1':['Joe','Sal', 'Murry','Q'], 
         '2':['Dana','White'],
         '3':['ice','cream','water','cola','Butter']}

def printMyInput(mystring):
    time.sleep(random.randint(1,4))  # random sleep time
    print(mystring)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    freeze_support()  # needed for Windows
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
       for k in input:
          print('>> Process ', k)
          procs = [executor.submit(printMyInput, x) for x in input[k]]
          results = [p.result() for p in procs]  # block until results are gathered
          print('>> Done Process ', k)
```

Comment: Why is the first for loop is above the with statement? Can it also be within the 'with'? And the code will not contiue to run the lines after the 'results' if there were any? While executing the processes?

Comment: You can put the `with` outside the loop and the executor will still process sequentially. However the `print` statements will occur together before any processing occurs. Note that it may run sequentially just because that is the order they are submitted.

Comment: I did some testing. Changing the loop structure will cause issues. Answer updated.

Comment: Answer updated again. You can switch the loop structure if you change the results code.